# Convert FileURL or Data URL to Blob format

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm trying to implement Camera on my ionic app. I was successfully able to make the camera part working. I was able to take pictures and show them on screen, when user selects save, I need to upload picture to back end system via API call. API accepts only BLOB format. 
With Camera, I'm able to capture image in both Data URL and File URL format. I tried to convert these formats into BLOB and with help of some online postings.
Code to open camera is like below.

```
openCamera(){
const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  sourceType:this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
}

this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
 // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
 // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
//  this.picTaken = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;     
//  this.blobFormat = this.getbase64toBlob(this.picTaken);

 //File URL
 this.picTaken = imageData; 
 this.getFiletoBlob(this.picTaken);

}, (err) => {
 // Handle error  
});
```

}

Data URL to BLOB my code is like below. Problem i'm facing with this code is "blob" variable contains only "Size" and "Type", there is no binary data in blob variable, when it is returning, here is what blob variable contains[image: here is what blob variable contains]. There is no binary data available in this.

```
getbase64toBlob(base64Data){
let contentType ='image/png';
let sliceSize = 512;    
base64Data = base64Data.replace(/data\:image\/(jpeg|jpg|png)\;base64\,/gi,'');

let byteCharacters = atob(base64Data);
let byteArrays = [];
for(let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize){
  let slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset+sliceSize);

  let byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
  for(let i=0; i < slice.length; i++){
   byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  let byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
  byteArrays.push(byteArray);
}
let blob = new Blob(byteArrays,{type: contentType});
return blob;
```

}

As Data URL is not working, I tried with File URL to Blob and code is like below. Control never reaches "imgBlob.name = 'Test Image';" line in debugging mode and no error as well. Looks like it is not doing anything. Attachments array is 0 all the time. I installed cordova-plugin-file already.

```
if(this.platform.is('android')){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
     window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(file,(entry) => {
      console.log(entry);
      entry.file((resFile) => {
        console.log(resFile);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = (evt: any) => {
          var imgBlob: any = new Blob([evt.target.result],{type:'image/jpeg'});
          imgBlob.name = 'Test Image';
          attachments.push(imgBlob);
          console.log(evt);
          resolve(imgBlob);
        };
        reader.onerror = (e) =>{
          console.log('Failed file read:'+e.toString());
          reject(e);
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(resFile);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

For now I'm testing only on Android device. Could you please advice where I'm going wrong.